# Segmentation fault when run an application out of makefile

Tags: c++, memory, makefile, segmentation-fault, armadillo

I had a program and I could only run it from `Makefile` otherwise it would give me this error:

> Segmentation fault (core dumped)

But if I ran the application from `Makefile` it would be ok. I have simplified my code:

This is my make file:

```
all: 
    g++ aaa.cpp
run:
    ./a.out
```

and this is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <armadillo>

class CModel
{
public:
    arma::mat::fixed<5,10000000> buffer;
};


int main()
{
    CModel m1, m2;
    std::cout<<"run successfully"<<std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

It seem this is a problem with memory occupation when it is out of makefile but how come does it work when it is inside makefile?

```
$ make
g++ aaa.cpp
$ make run
./a.out
run successfully
$ ./a.out
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

**Additional info:**

OS: Linux (Ubuntu)

To use armadillo matrix library:

```
sudo apt-get install libarmadillo-dev
```

Comment: Using a fixed size matrix with such a large size is a bad idea. Typically the stack for a given program is limited, and fixed size matrices use the stack. It would be better to declare the matrix simply as `arma::mat buffer`, and then use `buffer.set_size(5,10000000)` in the class constructor.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have armadillo so I cannot test your code. However by looking at it I'm guessing you have a stack overflow. Which is a particular time of segmentation fault.

It is not uncommon for a segmentation fault to come and go depending on how the program is run (and the positions of the stars etc etc).

Try reducing the size of your stack. Try:

```
arma::mat::fixed<5,1000> buffer;
```

Instead of:

```
arma::mat::fixed<5,10000000> buffer;
```

Or if it really does have to be that size put it on the heap instead of the stack (use the new/delete). High memory usage instances should not be on the stack and always on the heap.

Comment: I know that this is due to stackoverflow. But I really need that memory. I dont know how to run it the way that makefile runs it without any problem. I also dont think 80MB is very huge memory allocation.

Comment: Run `ulimit -s unlimited` at the bash prompt to give yourself unbounded stack size.

Comment: @ar2015 if you need the 80MB then use the heap not the stack. Make the member variable a pointer and use "new" to create it in the constructor and "delete" it in the deconstructor.

Answer (score 0):

Use heap instead of stack:

```
int main()
{
    CModel *m1 = new CModel;
    CModel *m2 = new CModel;
    std::cout<<"run successfully"<<std::endl;
    delete m1;
    delete m2;
    return 0;
}
```

Of course, you'll need to use m1->SomeMember instead of m1.SomeMember